# Cortar una linea específica de un archivo y pegarlo en otro

Tags: linux, bash

He buscado la forma de poder cortar una linea de un archivo y esta pegarla en otro, sin que quede rastro de esa linea en el primero. Necesito hacer esto por que los datos del archivo dos(Que esta en fomato json) tengo que introducirlo en una base de datos, de esta forma puedo insertar valores sin que se repitan en la base de datos.
Estoy tratando de hacerlo con un bucle while que recorre el primer archivo linea a linea. Sabeis alguna manera de poder hacerlo?El siguiente codigo que adjunto es en bash. Gracias de adelanto
Un saludo

```
    while read linea;
            do
            varnombre=$(echo "$linea" | cut -d " " -f 3 | cut -d "/" -f 1)
            data=$(echo "$linea" | cut -d ":" -f 12 | cut -d "," -f 1 | sed -e "s/^.//" -e "s/.$//")
            hora=$(echo "$linea" | cut -d "T" -f 1 | cut -d "." -f 1)
            fecha=$(echo "$linea" | cut -d "T" -f 4 | cut -d ":" -f 2 | sed -e "s/^.//")
            echo echo {'"nombre"':'"'$varnombre'"','"'data'"':'"'$data'"','"'hora'"':'"'$hora'"','"'fecha'"':'"'$fecha'"'} >> /home/user/logprueba.json
       
            done < /home/indotem/log2.txt
 php sql.php
            done
```

Comment: `cmd` no forma parte de Linux que yo sepa creo que te refieres al terminal de Linux.

Comment: @DanielBriceño recuerda que puedes editar la pregunta si así lo requiere.

Comment: Muchas gracias. @Adrián

Comment: No vuelvas a preguntar lo mismo. En [Cortar una linea de texto de un archivo a otro en Bash o linux](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/437690/83) dale a `edit` e introduce los detalles relevantes.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Cortar una linea de texto de un archivo a otro en Bash o linux](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/437690/cortar-una-linea-de-texto-de-un-archivo-a-otro-en-bash-o-linux)

Answer (score 2):

Respuesta tomada de [Cortar líneas específicas de un fichero y pegarlo al final de otro](https://askubuntu.com/a/1041509/1095355)

Puedes utilizar el comando `sed` para escribir un conjunto de líneas a otro fichero mientras lo eliminas del fichero actual u origen de la siguiente manera:

```
sed -i -e 'N, M { w output.txt
d }' input.txt
```

Donde:

- `N` y `M` son el nº de líneas.
- La opción `-i` hace que `sed` guarde los cambios en el fichero origen
- El comando `d` elimina esas líneas.
- Al mismo tiempo, `w output.txt` hace que las líneas eliminadas se copien en el fichero.
- Las dos líneas separadas en el comando es porque `sed` así lo requiere, que el nombre de `w` sea una nueva línea.

---

Siguiendo el siguiente ejemplo:

Supongiendo que tengo las siguientes 5 líneas en el fichero `file_one.txt`:

```
$ -> cat file_one.txt 
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
```

Y quiero cortar la línea 2 al fichero `file_two.txt`. Podría hacer lo siguiente:

```
# Creamos una variable con el comando:
$ -> command=' { w file_two.txt
d }'
```

```
# Ejecutamos el comando `sed` con el comando intermedio:
$ -> sed -i -e "2 $command" file_one.txt

# Leemos el destino y vemos que está la segunda línea:
$ -> cat file_two.txt
Line 2

# Leemos el primer fichero y vemos que la primera línea está eliminada:
$ -> cat file_one.txt 
Line 1
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
```

Comment: Hola Adrián, gracias por contestar. He probado el siguiente codigo y funciona correcto, es parecido a lo que quiero. Lo que exactamente necesito, es eliminar la variable linea que corresponde a las lineas que va leyendo el bucle del archivo uno.

Comment: Hola, Rodrigo. Mmm, no me queda muy claro. ¿Necesitas que c/u de las líneas que vayas leyendo, las vaya borrando una a una? Si es así, podrías hacerlo perfectamente con lo que te comenté, puedes colocar un contador y contar las líneas y de esta manera sabes cual es la iteración actual. En caso de que no sea lo que necesitas edita, por favor, la pregunta para tener más información.